# При Vue create выходит ERROR command failed: yarn

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yarn

```
$ vue create test
 ERROR  Failed to get response from https://registry.yarnpkg.com/vue-cli-version-marker


Vue CLI v4.5.4
Failed to check for updates
? Please pick a preset: Default ([Vue 2] babel, eslint)


Vue CLI v4.5.4
Failed to check for updates
✨  Creating project in C:\Users\Pavel\Documents\OwnProjects\MEVN\test.
�  Initializing git repository...
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...

yarn install v1.22.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@vue%2fcli-plugin-babel: unable to verify the first certificate".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\j.jyldyzbekov\\Documents\\OwnProjects\\MEVN\\test\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.        
 ERROR  command failed: yarn
```

Comment: yarn --version  что выдает?

Comment: Показывает версию 1.22.4

Comment: Мб попробовать через NPM сделать, как вариант.
Поменять на него через vue config --set packageManager npm.

Comment: С npm он вообще застыл и не устанавливает вот как уже 5 мин

Comment: Спасибо чувак помогло!

Comment: вот решение для таких как я кто не любить стандартный npm pm

Comment: yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g